# Trigger save on WysiHat editor on publish page?

Tags: add-on-development, jquery, richtext

I'm writing an EE module where I need access to the text of the EE rich text field (a modified version of the WysiHat editor).

When the field is edited, I need to trigger the logic to save the value back to the hidden textarea.

Based on the api docs (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/cp_javascript/rte/wysihat_api.html), this should be very simple

```
$('.WysiHat-field').each(function(){
    editor = $(this).data('wysihat');
    editor.updateField();
});
```

But nothing I try will give me access to the editor instances.  The 'editor' variable comes back undefined every time.  Any ideas?

Thanks.